# Using Mod_Rewrite in HTTPD.CONF file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I want to rewrite URLs so when a user goes to;

`http://www.example.com/applications/newWeb/www/index.php?page=48&thiscontent=2660&date=2013-10-11&pubType=0&PublishTime=09:30:00&from=home&tabOption=1`

and if the URL contains `thiscontent=2660` (which in this example above, it does) I want to redirect them to;

`http://www.example.come/index.php/publications/finance-and-economics/departmental-resources`

I have about 30 different `thiscontent=XXXX` types and imagine I’ll have to copy and edit this rule 30 different times for any links to my old website still knocking around out there.

I have access to my httpd.conf file but have never done a mod_rewrite before.

I also don't really need these showing up in the error logs as 301s. Will that happen? Because at the moment there are hundreds!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to make sure mod_rewrite is loaded. This line should be uncommented in your httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then you can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)thiscontent=2660(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?applications/newWeb/www/index\.php$ http://www.example.come/index.php/publications/finance-and-economics/departmental-resources? [L,R=301]
```

And yeah, you'll need to setup each one specifically, so you'll need 30 of those (but only need `RewriteEngine On` once. You can also put these rules in an htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: +1 Jon. I would recommend that you suggest OP to use `thiscontent=(2660|1234|..)` to avoid repeating the rule if target URL is the same.

Comment: Can you expand on the `(^|&)` and `(&|$)` syntax please? Or tell me what this is called so I can look it up and learn it? I have not used it before..

Comment: @MikeLovely The `(<something>|<something else)` means one thing or the other. The `(^|&)` means the beginning of the string, or a `&`, while the `(&|$)` means a `&` or the end of the string.

Comment: Do I have to wrap my rewrite rules in a `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block?

Comment: @MikeLovely no, that's only if you wanted to port your stuff to another server that doesn't have mod_rewrite loaded

Comment: I did a test. When I go to the page above it now redirects to `http://www.example.com/index.php/publications/finance-and-economics/departmental-resources[L,R=301]?page=48&thiscontent=2660&date=2013-10-11&pubType=0&PublishTime=09:30:00&from=home&tabOption=1` - which is wrong. I need to remove everything after the word `resources` from the URL string

Comment: @JonLin Yes. That was the issue. Thank you. I've added in two more rules now. and I've put one at the end that redirects to just `http://www.example.com` and I removed the `(&|$)` from the end of the RewriteCond. That way, until I get around to doing all 30, that last one just sends them to the home page.